# Encyrpting a string using Triple DES in c#?

Tags: java, c#, encryption, des, ecb

I am trying to write a c# program that will encrypt a string using an API key. The API key is generate by a third party payment gateway. The documentation is provided in java and I was able to encrypt the string in java but I tried to encrypt the string using the c# code and it generated a different result. This is what I tried so far.
java -

```
 public static String harden(String unencryptedString) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    String key ="***************";
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
    byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(key.getBytes("utf-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);

    for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
        keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
    }

    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

    byte[] plainTextBytes = unencryptedString.getBytes("utf-8");
    byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
    byte[] base64Bytes;

           base64Bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(buf);

    String base64EncryptedString = new String(base64Bytes);

    return base64EncryptedString;
}
```

c# code -

```
public TripleDES CreateDES(string key)
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        TripleDES des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        des.Key = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key));
        des.IV = new byte[des.BlockSize / 8];
        return des;
    }

    public  byte[] Encryption(string PlainText, string key)
    {
        TripleDES des = CreateDES(key);
        ICryptoTransform ct = des.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] input = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(PlainText);
        return ct.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
    }
```

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(PlainText)` - that's using UTF-16, but your Java code is using UTF-8...

Comment: 2 key triple DES, MD5, blast from the past?

Comment: You're extending your 3DES key from 128 bit to 192 bit in Java, but you forgot to do that in C#.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the remark of Jon, the `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` defaults to CBC mode encryption / decryption. You would need to specify ECB mode for C#, noting that ECB mode is insecure.

---

Actually, to provide full security, the ciphertext *should* always be different for each encryption / decryption with the same key. That's what the (random) IV is for in CBC mode.

---

Nowadays we try to use an authenticated cipher such as AES / GCM, preferably within a secure protocol. For instance one that uses a secure key derivation method that is not MD5.